# facing error while unmarshaling from sml to java

Tags: java, soap, jaxb

```
Caused by: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not unmarshal to [class com.vodafone.partnerservices.paymentpage.decoupling.response.beans.v2.ErResponse]: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"er-response"). Expected elements are <{http://localhost:8080/decoupling/schemas/v2/common}er-response>,<{}full-account-v2>,<{}full-accounts-response>,<{}get-next-payment-amount-response-v2>,<{}selfcare-full-subscriptions-v2>,<{}selfcare-full-transactions-v2>; nested exception is javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"er-response"). Expected elements are <{http://localhost:8080/decoupling/schemas/v2/common}er-response>,<{}full-account-v2>,<{}full-accounts-response>,<{}get-next-payment-amount-response-v2>,<{}selfcare-full-subscriptions-v2>,<{}selfcare-full-transactions-v2>
    at org.springframework.http.converter.xml.AbstractXmlHttpMessageConverter.readInternal(AbstractXmlHttpMessageConverter.java:75)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:199)
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:113)
    ... 94 more
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"er-response"). Expected elements are <{http://localhost:8080/decoupling/schemas/v2/common}er-response>,<{}full-account-v2>,<{}full-accounts-response>,<{}get-next-payment-amount-response-v2>,<{}selfcare-full-subscriptions-v2>,<{}selfcare-full-transactions-v2>
```

classes look like this

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "payload"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "er-response")
public class ErResponse
    implements Serializable, Element
{

    private final static long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected PayloadType payload;
```

Payloadtype looks like:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "payloadType", namespace = "http://localhost:8080/decoupling/schemas/v2/common", propOrder = {
    "any"
})
public class PayloadType
    implements Serializable, javax.xml.bind.Element
{

    private final static long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
    protected SelfcareFullSubscriptionsV2 any;
```

SelfcareFullSubscriptionsV2 looks like:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "subscription"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "selfcare-full-subscriptions-v2", namespace = "")
public class SelfcareFullSubscriptionsV2
    implements Serializable, Element
{

    private final static long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    protected List<Subscription> subscription;
```

Not able to understand what is the issue, any pointer will be helpful.

Comment: The error message states: `unexpected element (uri:"", local:"er-response")`. Later it's also states, that one of the expected elements is "{http://localhost:8080/decoupling/schemas/v2/common}er-response". It means, that  element "er-response" has no namespace, but it should have "http://localhost:8080/decoupling/schemas/v2/common". It seems that class ErResponse misses namespace definition. If JAXB classes were written manually, you should add it. If they were generated by some plugin, you should check plugin configuration.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried that but after that also I am facing exception. Should I add it in all Subclasses as well ? Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"er-response"). Expected elements are <{http://localhost:8080/decoupling/schemas/v2/common}er-response>,<{}full-account-v2>,<{}full-accounts-response>,<{}get-next-payment-amount-response-v2>,<{}selfcare-full-subscriptions-v2>,<{}selfcare-full-transactions-v2>

Comment: It depends on the definitions of XML messages. Were your JAXB classes generated by some plugin from WSDL or XSD files? Could you add to your question plugin configuration and excerpts from WSDLs / XSDs?